# Помогите найти ошибку в js скрипте

Tags: javascript, form, валидация, checkbox, отладчик

Написала код для формы Регистрации и Входа. Изначально надо зарегистрироваться. Форма проверяет на валидность вводимые данные в поле "почта","пароль" и наличие галочки в чекбоксе (вот тут где-то как я понимаю код дает сбой) и после нажатия на кнопку "Зарегистрироваться" введенные данные сохраняются в localStorage и форма регистрации переключается на форму входа. В форме входа поля так же должны проходить проверку, но уже на соответствие сохраненным в localStorage данным. Но скрипт прекращает от отрабатывать еще в форме регистрации в момент кликания по чекбоксу. Помогите найти ошибку пожалуйста.

JS:

```
'use strict'

//Переменные
//формы
const form_a = document.querySelector('#form-entr');
const form_b = document.querySelector('#form');

//авторизация и регистрация
const toformReg = document.querySelector('#form1');
const toformEntr = document.querySelector('#form2');

//подзаголовки
const preheader = document.querySelector('#preheader');
const preheader_entr = document.querySelector('#preheader_entr');

//переменная для проверки валидации почты
const emailChecker = /^(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+\.)+[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]{2,})$/iu;

//почта
const emailField = document.querySelector('#e-mail');
const email_entr = document.querySelector('#e-mail_entr');

//пароли
const password = document.querySelector('#password');
const password_entr = document.querySelector('#password_entr');

//звезды
const star1 = document.querySelector('#star1');
const star2 = document.querySelector('#star2');
const star3 = document.querySelector('#star3');

//ошибки
const error = document.querySelector('#error');
const errorpass = document.querySelector('#errorpass');
const errorpass2 = document.querySelector('#errorpass2');
const errorpass3 = document.querySelector('#errorpass3');
const errorEntr = document.querySelector('#errorEntr');

//чекбокс
const checkbox1 = document.querySelector('#box1');
const checkbox2 = document.querySelector('#box2');

//кнопки
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
const btn_entr = document.querySelector('#btn_entr');

//переменные сравнения
let a = false;
let b = false;
let c = false;
let d = false;
let e = false;
let f = false;


//переключение между окнами при нажатии на надпись "Зарегистрироваться"
function goToRegistration(){
  form_a.style.visibility = 'collapse';
  form_b.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
toformReg.addEventListener('click', goToRegistration);

//переключение между окнами при нажатии на надпись "Авторизоваться"
function goToEntrance(){
  form_b.style.visibility = 'collapse';
  form_a.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
toformEntr.addEventListener('click', goToEntrance);

//Форма регистрации
//проверка е-mail на валидность
function isEmailValid(value) {
  return emailChecker.test(value);
}


function onInput() {
  if (isEmailValid(emailField.value)) {
    emailField.style.borderColor = 'green';
    error.style.display = 'none';
    preheader.style.color = 'black';
    star1.style.color = 'black';
    a = true;
  } else {
    emailField.style.borderColor = 'red';
    preheader.style.color = 'red';
    error.style.display = 'initial';
    star1.style.color = 'red';
    a = false;
  }
}
emailField.addEventListener('keyup', onInput);


//проверка пароля на валидность
function passValidation() {
  if (password.value.length === 0) {
    password.style.borderColor = 'red';
    errorpass.style.display = 'initial';
    preheader_entr.style.color = 'red';
    errorpass2.style.display = 'none';
    star2.style.color = 'red';
    b = false;
  } else if (password.value.length > 0 && password.value.length < 8) {
    password.style.borderColor = 'red';
    errorpass2.style.display = 'initial';
    preheader_entr.style.color = 'red';
    star2.style.color = 'red';
    b = false;
  } else {
    password.style.borderColor = 'green';
    errorpass.style.display = 'none';
    errorpass2.style.display = 'none';
    preheader_entr.style.color = 'black';
    star2.style.color = 'black';
    b = true; 
  }
}
password.addEventListener('keyup', passValidation);

//проверка чекбокса
function checkboxValid() {
  if (!checkbox1.checked === false) {
    checkbox1.style.borderColor = 'black';
    errorpass3.style.display = 'none';
    c = true;
  } else {
    checkbox1.style.borderColor = 'red';
    errorpass3.style.display = 'initial';
    star3.style.color = 'red';
    c = false;
  }
}
checkbox1.addEventListener('change', checkboxValid);

//проверка на соответствие всем 3-м условиям регистрации
function formValidation(evt) {
  if (a === true && b === true && c === true) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log(emailField.value);
    console.log(password.value);

    //запись данных в localStorage

    //запись e-mail
    let emailLS = {email: emailField.value};
    let serialEmailLS = JSON.stringify(emailLS);
    localStorage.setItem("KeyEmail", serialEmailLS);

    //запись пароля
    let passwordLS = {password: password.value};
    let serialPasswordLS = JSON.stringify(passwordLS);
    localStorage.setItem("KeyPass", serialPasswordLS);
  } 
  //переключение на окно входа
  goToEntrance();
}  
form_b.addEventListener('submit', formValidation)


//Форма Вход
  
//переменные пароля и почты сохраненные в localStorage
let returnEMailLS = {};
let returnPasswordLS = {};


//проверка e-mail в форме Вход
function emailEnterValidation(){
  returnEMailLS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("KeyEmail"));
  if (email_entr.value === returnEMailLS.email){
  email_entr.style.borderColor = 'green';
  preheader_entr.style.color = 'black';
  star1.style.color = 'black';
  d = true;
} else {
  email_entr.style.borderColor = 'red';
  preheader_entr.style.color = 'red';
  star1.style.color = 'red';
  errorEntr.style.display = 'initial';
  d = false;
}
}
email_entr.addEventListener('keyup',emailEnterValidation);


//проверка пароля
function passwordEnterValidation(){
  returnPasswordLS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("KeyPass"));
  if (password_entr.value === returnPasswordLS.password){
  password_entr.style.borderColor = 'green';
  errorpass.style.display = 'none';
  errorEntr.style.display = 'none';
  preheader_entr.style.color = 'black';
  star2.style.color = 'black'
    e = true;
} else {
  preheader_entr.style.color = 'red';
  password_entr.style.borderColor = 'red';
  errorEntr.style.display = 'initial';
  star2.style.color = 'red';
  e = false;
}
}
password_entr.addEventListener('keyup', passwordEnterValidation);

//проверка чекбокса
function enterCheckboxValidation() {
  if (!checkbox2.checked === false) {
    checkbox2.style.borderColor = 'black';
    errorpass3.style.display = 'none';
    f = true;
  } else {
    checkbox2.style.borderColor = 'red';
    errorpass3.style.display = 'initial';
    star3.style.color = 'red';
    f = false;
  }
}
checkbox2.addEventListener('change', checkboxValid);

//проверка  на соответствие условиям входа
function validEnter(evt){
  
  if (d === true && e === true && f === true){
    evt.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = 'empty_index.html';
  }
}
form_a.addEventListener('submit', validEnter);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../module_two_javascript/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../module_two_javascript/style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"> 
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!--Форма "Вход"-->

  <form class = "form-a" id = "form-entr">
  
    <p class = "form-a__registration" id = "form1">Зарегистрироваться</p>
    <h1 class = "form-a__header">Вход</h1>

    <p class = "form-a__preheader" id = "preheader_entr">E-mail</p>

    <div class = "form-a__container">
      <span class = "form-a__star" id = "star1">*</span>
      <input class = "form-a__field" type = "text" id = "e-mail_entr" placeholder = "Введите e-mail">
    </div>
   
    <p class = "form-a__error" id = "error">Поле обязательно для заполнения</p>

    <p class = "form-a__preheader" id = "preheaderpass">Пароль</p>

    <div class = "form-a__container">
      <span class = "form-a__star" id = "star2">*</span>
    <input class = "form-a__field" type = "password" id = "password_entr" placeholder = "Введите пароль">
    </div>
    
    <p class = "form-a__error" id = "errorpass">Поле обязательно для заполнения</p>
    <p class = "form-a__error" id = "errorEntr">Пароль или логин неверный</p>

    <div class = "form-a__pc">
      <div class = "form-a__checkbox">

        <div class = "form-a__container">
          <span class = "form-a__star" id = "star3">*</span>
        <input class = "form-a__box" type = "checkbox" id = "box1" value = "check">
        </div>
        
        <label for = "box" class = "form-a__text">Я согласен получать обновления на почту</label>
      </div>
      <p class = "form-a__error" id = "errorpass3">Поле обязательно для заполнения</p>
    </div>

    <button class = "form-a__send" id = "btn_entr" type = "submit">
            Войти
    </button>
  </form>


<!--Форма "Регистрация"-->

    <form class = "form-b" id = "form">

      <p class = "form-b__registration" id = "form2">Авторизоваться</p>
      <h1 class = "form-b__header">Регистрация</h1>
  
      <p class = "form-b__preheader" id = "preheader">E-mail</p>
  
    <div class = "form-b__container">
      <span class = "form-b__star" id = "star">*</span>
      <input class = "form-b__field" type="text" id = "e-mail" placeholder = "Введите e-mail">
    </div>
  
      <p class = "form-b__error" id = "error">Поле обязательно для заполнения</p>
      <p class = "form-b__preheader" id = "preheaderpass">Пароль</p>
  
    <div class = "form-b__container">
      <span class = "form-b__star" id = "star">*</span>
      <input class = "form-b__field" type = "password" id = "password" placeholder="Введите пароль">
    </div> 
      
      <p class = "form-b__error" id = "errorpass">Поле обязательно для заполнения</p>
      <p class = "form-b__error" id = "errorpass2">Пароль должен содержать как минимум 8 символов</p>
  
      <div class = "form-b__pc">
        <div class = "form-b__checkbox">
  
        <div class = "form-b__container"> 
          <span class = "form-b__star" id = "star">*</span>
          <input class = "form-b__box" type="checkbox" id = "box2" value = "check">
         </div> 
  
          <label for = "box" class = "form-b__text">Я согласен получать обновления на почту
          </label>
        </div>
        <p class = "form-b__error" id = "errorpass3">Поле обязательно для заполнения</p>
      </div>
  
      <button class = "form-b__send" id = "btn" type = "submit">
              Регистрация
      </button>
    </form>

    <script src = "../module_two_javascript/script_exam.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    max-width: 1440px;
    max-height: 769px;
    background-color: #1B2473;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    position:relative;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width:768px) {
      .body{
        max-width: 768px;
      }
    
  }
  
.form-a{
    position:absolute;
    top:82px;
    left:412px;
    width: 600px;
    height: fit-content;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top:82px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    visibility: visible;
}

.form-b{
    position:absolute;
    top:82px;
    left:412px;
    width: 600px;
    height: fit-content;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top:82px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    visibility: collapse;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .form-a, .form-b{
    width: 728px;
    height: fit-content;
    }
}

.form-a__preheader, .form-b__preheader{
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    
    color: #787878;
    margin-left:45px;
    margin-bottom:7px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    .form-a__preheader, .form-b__preheader{
    font-size: 24px;
    } 
}

.form-a__header{
    width: 115px;
    height: 50px;
    
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    
    color: #787878;

    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-top:15px;
}

.form-b__header{
    width: 115px;
    height: 50px;
    
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    
    color: #787878;

    margin-left:25%;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-top:20px;
}


@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    .form-a__header, .form-b__header{
    width: 138px;
    font-size: 60px;
    }
}

.form-a__field, .form-b__field{
    width: 509px;
    height: 49px;
    
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #787878;
    border-radius: 10px;

    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:0px;

    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 36px;

    color: #CCCCCC;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    .form-a__field, .form-b__field{
    width: 638px;
    height: 49px;
    } 
}

.form-a__error, .form-b__error{
  display:none;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #CB2424;  
  margin-left:45px;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-bottom:12px;
}

.form-a__star, .form-b__star{
    width: 7px;
    height: 12px;
    color: #787878;
}

.form-a__pc, .form-b__pc{
  width: 638px;
  height:fir-content;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:flex-start;
}

.form-a__box, .form-b__box{
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;

    border: 2px solid #787878;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    .form-a__box, .form-b__box{
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
    }  
}

.form-a__checkbox, .form-b__checkbox{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.form-a__text, .form-b__text{
    width: 278px;
    height: 16px;

    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;

    color: #787878;
    margin-top:3px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    .form-a__text, .form-b__text{
        width: 358px;
        font-size: 18px;
    }  
}

.form-a__send, .form-b__send{
    width: 180px;
    height: 52px;

    background-color: #1A226B;
    border-radius: 10px;

    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 16px;

    color: #FFFFFF;

    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-bottom:26px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    .form-a__send, .form-b__send{
    width: 220px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 32px;
    }  
}

.form-a__container, .form-b__container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}

.form-a__star, .form-b__star{
    margin-left:34px;
    margin-right:4px;
}

.form-a__registration, .form-b__registration{
    width: 137px;
    height: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #1A226B;
    margin-left:70%;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.form-a__registration:hover{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: green;
}

.form-b__registration:hover{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: green;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .body {
    max-width: 768px;
  }
}

.form {
  width: 600px;
  height: 412px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 82px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .form {
    width: 728px;
    height: 697px;
  }
}

.form__preheader {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #787878;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__preheader {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

.form__header {
  width: 115px;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #787878;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 26px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__header {
    width: 138px;
    font-size: 60px;
  }
}

.form__field {
  width: 509px;
  height: 49px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #787878;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #CCCCCC;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__field {
    width: 638px;
    height: 49px;
  }
}

.form__error {
  display: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #CB2424;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.form__star {
  width: 7px;
  height: 12px;
  color: #787878;
}

.form__pc {
  width: 638px;
  height: fir-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.form__box {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 2px solid #787878;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__box {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
  }
}

.form__checkbox {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.form__text {
  width: 278px;
  height: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #787878;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__text {
    width: 358px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

.form__send {
  width: 180px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: #1A226B;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 26px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__send {
    width: 220px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 32px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Откройте "Инструменты разработчика" в браузере, вкладку Console, какие-нибудь ошибки там есть?

Comment: "В форме входа поля так же должны проходить проверку, но уже на соответствие сохраненным в localStorage данным." - вот здесь можете пояснить? Зачем их проверять? Для чего эти данные, в принципе, сохраняются в локальном хранилище? IMHO лучше, когда URL для входа и регистрации разный. И изначально не нужно регистрироваться, изначально нужно залогиниться, а в форму входа добавить ссылку на страницу регистрации. А так у вас получается на одной странице и вход, и регистрация... Tолько не говорите, что добавите сюда-же форму для восстановления пароля : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const checkbox1 = document.querySelector('#box1'); //вход
const checkbox2 = document.querySelector('#box2'); //регистрация
```

Если не ошибаюсь тут напутали `checkbox1` и `checkbox2`. В форма регистрации у вас сейчас `checkbox1`, а должно быть `checkbox2`, поменяйте на  `checkbox2` и должно сохраниться в  localStorage

```
function checkboxValid() {
if (!checkbox1.checked === false) {
checkbox1.style.borderColor = 'black';
errorpass3.style.display = 'none';
c = true;
} else {
checkbox1.style.borderColor = 'red';
errorpass3.style.display = 'initial';
star3.style.color = 'red';
c = false;
}
}
checkbox1.addEventListener('change', checkboxValid);
```

Comment: Александр, огромное спасибо! Именно это и являлось причиной нерабочего кода!

Comment: @Kolamik пожалуйста - удачи ))